# PHP Fatal error: Class 'FacebookAds\Object\AdAccount' not found in

Tags: php, facebook

I am using Facebook Ads API to pull data from ads Reporting.
Below is my code :

```
<?php

use FacebookAds\Object\AdAccount;

$account = new AdAccount('act_xxxx');

$params = array(
    'date_preset'=>'last_28_days',
    'data_columns'=>"['adgroup_id']",
);

$stats = $account->getReportsStats(null, $params);


foreach($stats as $stat) {
    echo "is it inside the foreach loop \n";
    echo $stat->impressions;
    echo $stat->actions;
}
?>
```

I get FacebookAds/Object/AdAccount not found. I checked the path and everything looks correct. any idea, what could be the reason for this error. I am not a PHP Expert, so please do correct me, if something is wrong with my code.

Comment: tag question with PHP

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function __autoload($class) { 
    require_once $class.".php";
}
```

Save this file as autoload.php in same directory then add below code at start

```
<?php
require_once('./autoload.php');
```

**Explanation:**

In your code you haven't included the file which contains the class      `FacebookAds\Object\AdAccount`. That's why it gives class not found error.

Above code will make sure that all necessary class files are include in code.